# Android GeoFire onDataChange delayed async execution

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am reading list of geo coordinates from FireBase DB using Geofire API and for each geo coordinate, i am reading additional details for geo coordinate.

the issue is that all there is a delay in reading additional details about user  on one geo coordinate using FireBase async design approach.

so what is happening is that the onDataChange is not executed for each geo coordinate and it is executed for one geo coordinate.

what i believe is that FireBase API reads list of geo coordinate in loop and for each geo coordinate, it kicks off on onDataChange method but there is a delay in reading details using onDataChange, FireBase API doesn't wait and continues to read other geo coordinate.

can anyone who is experienced in firebase db help me with this issue.

```
   geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()),1.80);

markers = new HashMap<String, Marker>();
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {

@Override

public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
try {
ref.child("user").child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
user= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
 {
 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
 }


 });
                                     return true;
}

});
```

[image]

Comment: Please add also your database structure. Is there a big ammount of data?

Comment: updated my data structure

Comment: can any one help me with this issue please